# OpenLayers/Leaflet render world borders

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, leaflet, borders

I am trying to show all world borders. Either using OpenLayers or Leaflet. World borders are taken from [here](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json). This code does not work.

What I am doing wrong?

```
var Map = {

  map: null,
  layer: null,

  initializeMap: function() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("World Map");
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.zoomTo(2);
    var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
    var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(); 
    map.addLayer(vector_layer);
    vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the map, it is necessary to declare the projection of the data, and the projection you want to be displayed.

The geojson data seems to be in EPSG:4326, while the OSM map you load is in EPSG:900913.

My own osm map starts with

```
            map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
            controls:[ new OpenLayers.Control.Zoomlevel(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({geodesic: true}),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'asscending':true}),


                       new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                       new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),

                       new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()],
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34),
                maxResolution: 156543.0399,
                numZoomLevels: 19,
                units: 'm',
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
```